# Proof order of proof encoded nodes

Tags: storage, trie

Does the **order of the Merkle proof encoded nodes matter for the state trie**?

I am working on Gossamer and for now we produce proofs *without considering order* of encoded nodes in Gossamer.
Now I am wondering if this can be problematic since the root node has its hash always as its encoding 32 bytes digest, unlike other trie nodes which can have their hash as their encoding if this one is less than 32 bytes.

Should we have (at least) the proof root node as the first encoded node in generated proofs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Comment edited with simplifications found in the comments**

There is no need to have an order in the proof node encodings. The solution I adopted so far (thanks @cheme) is to 'lazy decode' encodings as described below.

There is a single for loop iterating over the encoded proof nodes. This one has two tasks:

- find the root node and decode it
- record all other node encodings in a key value map from the node encoding hash digest to the node encoding

For each (non inlined) child of the root, the hash digest is looked up in our key value map and, if found, the matching node encoding gets decoded. In comparison with our previous solution to decode each node first, this solution also has the advantage to be more easily upgrade-able with the v1 state trie where the proof contains encoded proof nodes and eventually value byte slices (referenced by their hash digest).

<s>However, if the root node is not the first encoded node in the proof, one or more hash computations are 'lost' on node encodings smaller or equal to 32 bytes, until the root node is found. This is because:</s>

- For encoded nodes larger than 32 bytes, the blake2b hash has to be computed to get their Merkle value; no additional computational cost
- For encoded nodes smaller or equal to 32 bytes, their Merkle value is their encoding. The blake2b hash does not need to be computed to add them to the map of encoded nodes. However, because the root node Merkle value is always the hash of its encoding, we are here forced to hash it in order to compare it with the root hash given, until the root node is found.

On the other hand, practically it seems like the root node is often the first encoded node, so this should not have an impact out there.

Comment: Encoded node smaller or equal to 32 bytes (except if state root or a child trie state root) should not be part of the proof as individual encoded node. They should only be included in their parent encoded node.
But yes to get the root you need to hash some nodes.
If ordering is needed (for instance to avoid hashing all), compact proof are really more adequate. Only drawback with compact proof is that they don't support multiple consecutive state (in substrate there is an implementation for child state), but the use case does not really exists.

Comment: Very good point, thank you! Indeed, all encoded proof nodes are either root node, or a child root node, or a node with an encoding larger than 32 bytes. In all cases, their Merkle value is their encoding root hash. 

Hence in our implementation, each encoded proof node has to be hashed (to find the root and to store them in a map from hash to encoding), so the order of proof encoded nodes does not matter at all.

By 'compact proof', do you mean proofs containing both encoded nodes and node subvalues?

Answer (score 2):

In current substrate proof https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ee3eb8f2448cc1bb978c5d1564febd351c128bb0/primitives/trie/src/storage_proof.rs#L35 (not the compact one), node are somehow ordered by the internal structure (btree), but it was not always the case and order should not be an enforced for thing as rpc (still a sort is needed if storing proof on state in a deterministic way, that was the reason for us to switch to put thing in a btreeset).

Implementation should see all encoded nodes in the proof as a trie node, without looking at its size.
There is currently no restriction upon adding extra content in a proof (but I don't think there is incentive in doing so).

Yet indeed only the root nodes are allowed to be smaller than 32bytes.
So if a proof contains multiple node smaller than 32 bytes, it should indicate it contains content from two different states or all those smaller node are child trie roots.

Really the intent of this proof is to just be a set of encoded node.

I would not be to prone to make root node the first for this reason.

Comment: *Yet indeed only the root nodes are allowed to be smaller than 32bytes.*


I don't think only root nodes are allowed to be smaller than 32 bytes? From my understanding, root nodes encoding can be any size, but their Merkle value is always the blake2b 32 bytes hash digest of their encoding, whereas other non-root nodes can have their Merkle value as the digest of their encoding or as their encoding if this last one is smaller or equal to 32 bytes.

Comment: Yes you are correct any node can be less than 32 byte, but just the root node will need its merkle hash calculated (others node will be encoded directly in their parent node).